# Loopback AngularJS JavaScript SDK - Gruntfile plugin

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, angular-loopback

I'm following literally the official [loopback documentation for AngularJS Grunt plugin](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/AngularJS+Grunt+plugin) and I'm facing a problem during the creation of the task under the Grunt file.

The documentation is well done and In the **How to use the plugin** section it provides an very good example of implementation but it's not clear the meaning of `staging` and `production` sections.

I'm also interested to provide a different `urlBase` for the APIs cause my AngularJS application is served from a different address, so I added the `apiUrl` option, but when I start `loopback_sdk_angular` task from the Grunt file all goes well but it seems not considering my `apiUrl` option within `staging` or `production` sections (Tried both, nothing changed) building a `api.service.js` with `var urlBase = '/api'` instead of `var urlBase = 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/api'`.

My grunt file:

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-loopback-sdk-angular');

...
//grunt init config
...

loopback_sdk_angular: {
      services: {
        options: {
          input: 'server/server.js', output: 'client/services/api.services.js'
        }, staging: {
          options: {
            apiUrl: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/api'
          }
        }
//, production: {
//          options: {
//            apiUrl: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/api'
//          }
//        }
      }
    }


...

grunt.registerTask('generate-services', ['loopback_sdk_angular']);
//end
```

Could someone please explain me the meaning of that two sections and what I'm missing to make the `var urlBase` to assume the correct value of `http://127.0.0.1:3000/api`?

Answer (score 0):

> Could someone please explain me the meaning of that two sections and what I'm missing to make the var urlBase to assume the correct value of http://127.0.0.1:3000/api?

I got the same problem when I configured the loopback_sdk_angular plugin the way you did. However, the problem was resolved when the options and staging properties were directly under loopback_sdk_angular property instead of being within a services property.

```
loopback_sdk_angular: {
    options: {
      input: 'server/server.js', output: 'client/services/api.services.js'
    }, staging: {
      options: {
        apiUrl: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/api'
      }
    }
```

There may be a minor glitch in the [loopback AngularJS Grunt plugin documentation](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/AngularJS+Grunt+plugin). If you notice, the description for the loopback plugin follows the format that I used and that works fine. Whereas the format in the example doesn't work for both of us.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add global options to `loopback_sdk_angular` grunt task but you did it in a wrong way.`loopback_sdk_angular` can have options defined in two ways

1. Where you pass a global options configuration for all other tasks and every sub-tasks or section will have this options inherited in them

> Useful when you have a **common input and output** folder for each environment.

```
    // You were trying to achieve this.....
    loopback_sdk_angular: {
      options: {
        input: 'server/server.js', 
        output: 'client/services/api.services.js'
      }, 
      staging: { 
        //input and ouput are inherited from above global options
        options: {
        apiUrl: 'http://staging.url/api'
      },
      production: { 
        //input and output are inherited from above global options
        options: {
          apiUrl: 'http://production.url/api'
        }
    }
```

2. Where you have environment-specific options defined for each sub-tasks

> Useful when you have **different input and output** folder for environments.

```
    // But you actually did this 
    loopback_sdk_angular: {
      staging: { 
        options: {
          input: 'server/server.js', 
          // Different output folder for staging
          output: 'client/staging/services/api.services.js'
          apiUrl: 'http://staging.url/api'
        }
      },
      production: { 
        options: {
          apiUrl: 'http://production.url/api',
          input: 'server/server.js', 
          // Different output folder for production
          output: 'client/production/services/api.services.js'
        }
    }
```